# javascript array variable not incrementing inside ''form tag'' in an ejs file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am rendering variables from a js file to an ejs file and want to create a drop down list when I hover over a button. But the number of options to be listed is dynamic and is rendered from the js file. Suppose on hovering the button gives us 3 options like 1001, 1002 and 1003. When I click on any of the options I should get a pop up form  for each option.

I am using a for loop for traversing the array and to create that many pop up forms. But the problem is the for loop is not incrementing inside the "form tag". All the form generated refers to the data stored inside the zero-th index of the array.

```
<div class="dropdown" >
<button  class="dropbtn" >Node Management</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <table>
    <tr>
  <% for(var i in bmsData.node_arr){%>
    <a href="#" class="trigger_popup_fricc" onclick="openForm_node()"><%= bmsData.node_arr[i] %></a>
    <div class="hover_bkgr_fricc" id="myForm_node">
      <form action="/DataRetrieval/bmsnode" class="form-container" method="post">

        <span class="helper"></span>
          <div>
            <h1>Node Configuration</h1>
            <label for="node"><b>Node :<%= bmsData.node_arr[i] %></b></label>
            <input type="text"  name="Node" value="<%= bmsData.node_arr[i] %>" readonly></h1>

                <h2>Temperature</h2>
                <label for="lowerlimit"><b>Lower Limit</b></label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Lower Limit" name="LLTemperature" value="<%= bmsData.temp_lower[i]%>" required>

                <label for="upperlimit"><b>Upper Limit</b></label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Upper Limit" name="ULTemperature" value="<%= bmsData.temp_upper[i]%>" required>

                <h2>Relative Humidity</h2>
                <label for="lowerlimit"><b>Lower Limit</b></label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Lower Limit" name="LLRelativeHumidity" value="<%= bmsData.rh_lower[i]%>" required>

                <label for="upperlimit"><b>Upper Limit</b></label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Upper Limit" name="ULRelativeHumidity" value="<%= bmsData.rh_upper[i]%>" required>

                <h2>Ambient Light</h2>
                <label for="lowerlimit"><b>Lower Limit</b></label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Lower Limit" name="LLAmbientLight" value="<%= bmsData.al_lower[i]%>" required>

                <label for="upperlimit"><b>Upper Limit</b></label>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Upper Limit" name="ULAmbientLight" value="<%= bmsData.al_upper[i]%>" required>

            <button type="submit" class="btn">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm_node()">Close</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </tr>
</table>

  <%}%>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function openForm_node()
 {document.getElementById("myForm_node").style.display = "block";}
function closeForm_node() {document.getElementById("myForm_node").style.display = "none";}
</script>
```

Expected: the pop up form for node 1001 should show node name 1001 and configurations of node 1001, similarly for node 1002

Actual: the pop up form for all the nodes are showing node name and configurations of node 1001 which is stored in the 0th index of my array

Comment: Since you're using `bmsData.node_arr[i]` within the for loop, try changing the for loop to `<% for (var i = 0; i < bmsData.node_arr.length; i++) { %>`

Comment: You're creating multiple elements with `id="myForm_node"` (an `id` is supposed to be unique). The script at the end will always display the first. Here's a fiddle I wrote for a different question showing one way to solve this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/w209uvfk/

Comment: A different way is to pass the `i`: `onclick="openForm_node(<%= i %>)"` and use the parameter to grab the proper form element. Inline code is bad practice though.